# How to not run function if its a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, iphone, conditional-statements, browser-detection

I have a modal pop up function on my website, but i don't want this to run if the browser is smaller than 480px. I have found that if I put an if statement such as:

```
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerWidth > 480) {

 run function()
}
```

Then it should run only if the browsers innerWidth is > 480. However its not working and I think its because I have page scaling on this website. Can any one help me with a conditional statement if page scaling is on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

```
if (window.outerWidth && window.outerWidth > 480) {

}
```

Comment: if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iPhone/i) != "iphone" ) &&
   (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iPod/i) != "ipod")) {

Was the best solution so far. Just need to figure out what Android browsers are.